# read data from textfile and display in console

Tags: c++, fstream

I would like to read data from the text file stored in the following
path `C:\folder1\folder2\example.txt`
but my code is not working. I am receiving the message "Unable to open file" and yet the text file exists.Any correction will be highly appreciated.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
string filename, line;
SetCurrentDirectoryA( "C:\\folder1\\folder2\\" );

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("example.txt");
if (!inFile) {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    exit(1); // terminate with error
}

while (inFile >> line) {
    cout << line << endl ;
}

inFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `inFile.open("C:\\folder1\\folder2\\example.txt");`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried that but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    char buf[256];
    std::ifstream inFile("C:\\folder1\\folder2\\example.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }
    while (inFile >> buf) {
        std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I've just tried it and it works perfect